# SQL table aliases

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got a table called "email" with 2 columns, "von" and "zu".
Both contain varchar(20). I need to get a table containing every String that matches to a specific name. For example:
email:

```
von    |     zu
---------------
Finn   |    John
Finn   |    Lisa
Eric   |    Finn
Eric   |    Lisa
```

Now I need to get every matching name to "Finn". The result should look like this:

```
  X
-------
John
Lisa
Eric
```

My code looks like this:

```
Select X from 
(Select von as X from email where von = 'Finn'),
(Select zu as X from email where zu = 'Finn');
```

And I get the following error:

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what I did wrong? 
Greetings, Finn

Comment: Why don't you use UNION instead of the comma.

Comment: What you did wrong is that the sub queries need to have their own name so after the ) put something like `von` and `zu`  This is needed as the system will not be able to reference the field X without knowing the table, and you can't reference the inline view without an alias.  Even if you named the columns differently, I would think it wise to alias the inline views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not an answer, but a clarification what your own query does.**

---

```
Select X from 
(Select von as X from email where von = 'Finn') von_finn,
(Select zu as X from email where zu = 'Finn') zu_finn;
```

(I've added the missing table aliases.)

You are using an old join sytax here that was used in the 1980s. Nowadays we specify what join type we are using. In your case where there is no join criteria on the tables, that would be a cross join:

```
Select X
from (Select von as X from email where von = 'Finn') von_finn
cross join (Select zu as X from email where zu = 'Finn') zu_finn;
```

Let's look at the first subquery. You select `von` where `von` is 'Finn'. This is certainly a typo and you really wanted to select `zu`. Correct? This would give you the people who received an email from Finn. Same for the second subquery, where you'd get all people who sent an email to Finn. Cross joining means: take all senders and combine them with all receivers (i.e. get all combinations). With your sample data you'd get:

```
zu_finn.x | von_finn.x
----------+-----------
Eric      | John
Eric      | Lisa
```

Then you show `x`. But which one? `zu_finn.x` or `von_finn.x`? Either the DBMS will throw an ambiguity error (which would be preferable) or it would silently decide for one column, so you'd either show `Eric, Eric` or `John, Lisa`.

Many mistakes for a small query :-) I thought I'd tell you, so you can learn from it.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Haha I had to learn it in school. SQL is not my favorite topic. I understand what you mean. Very helpful !:)

Comment: And yes. That was a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Union. This should work for what you want.

```
Select von as X from email where von = 'Finn'
UNION ALL
Select zu as X from email where zu = 'Finn';
```

Comment: Keep in mind that duplicate rows are removed from the result when using a `UNION`, which might not be what this user is looking for.

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank you :) duplicated rows should be removed. It's for a social network which finds your contacts. :)

Comment: Heh, it is the `uniion` after all ;) thanks for taking into the count my coment, nevertheless :)